# How to assign value to specific rows in dataframe that match a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe on US Congressional races. I am wanting to mark several of these as abnormal. The list of abnormal ones is:

`abnormal_race = ["CA6", "CA27", "CA44", "LA6", "WA9", "LA1", "LA3", "CA5", "CA34", "CA40", "MS2", "NY6", "NY7", "NY8", "LA2", "MI13", "TX9", "TX20", "TX28", "TX30", "WA2", "AL7", "AZ7", "FL20", "FL21", "FL24", "GA5", "MA1", "MA4", "MA7", "MA8", "NY5", "NY16", "PA18", "VA3", "WI2"]`

The dataframe is called `a_m_d_8`. I started by assigning the `abnormal` column:

`a_m_d_8["abnormal"] = 0`

`a_m_d_8` has a column called `state_dist` with the two-letter designation for each state, and district number, for every congressional race in the dataset. It's in the same format as `abnormal_race` above. I want to check each row, and if its `state_dist` value is in `abnormal_race`, assign a value of 1, but have had trouble. My attempts so far have gotten a "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." error message.

An example attempt:

`a_m_d_8.loc[a_m_d_8.state_dist in abnormal_race, "abnormal"] = 1`

This threw the above error.

What does work for individual cases is:

`a_m_d_8.loc[a_m_d_8.state_dist == "AL7", "abnormal"] = 1`

This assigns a value of 1 to the "AL7" row. How should I go about doing this for all of the ones in `abnormal_race`? There must be a better way than just running the above for every one in `abnormal_race`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.isin(values)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to find whether elements in Series are contained in *values*.

```py
a_m_d_8.loc[a_m_d_8.state_dist.isin(abnormal_race), "abnormal"] = 1
```

The reason why you got the error is that `in` doesn't support Series object.

Comment: Damn, it was really that simple? Thanks for the help, man, much appreciated.